# Laravel 4 - Products search service

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my first attempt to build a search service. The problem is that the code I have looks very untidy, which will probably lead to other problems in the future. Here is what I have written so far:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Search;
use Product, Brand;

class ProductSearchService {
 public function search($data = array()) {
 $limit     = 10;
 $query     = isset($data) ? $data : "";
 $baseQuery = Product::take($limit);

 $brand = Brand::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->first();

 if($query) {
  if (!empty($brand)) {
    return $baseQuery
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('brand_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$brand->id.'%')->get();
  }

    return $baseQuery
      ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
      ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
    }
  }
}
```

How should I structure this service so that it will be cleaner and return more accurate results?

### **Solution**

The answers posted here were very helpful but I found another solution to this.

I used eager loading to reduce the number of queries and declared a base query, like so:

```
  $products = Product::with('brand')
              ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%');
```

while then I have used the `orWhereHas` method to search for any associated brands, like so:

```
  $products->orWhereHas('brand', function($q) use ($term) {
      $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
  });
```

and then return `$products->get()`

Comment: On a sidenote, why are you encoding to json and then immediatly decoding?

Comment: ->tojSon() is irrelevant here, you are encoding it to a json object and then you are decoding it. You are just doing something that is completely unnecessary and can just be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Search;

use Product, Brand;

class ProductSearchService {
    public function search($query) {

        $limit     = 10;

        $brand = Brand::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->first();

        $baseQuery = Product::take($limit)
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%');

        if (!empty($brand))
        {
            $baseQuery = $baseQuery->orWhere('brand_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$brand->id.'%')->get();
        }

        return $baseQuery->get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrote it for you, please note  that this is not perfect yet, also using LIKE for the brand_id isn't really a smart idea as an id is unique! This also means that searching for the name and description isn't needed either. You should just search on id when you got the id, if not, execute the 2 LIKE queries.

```
<?php 

    namespace Acme\Services\Search;

    use Product, Brand;

    class ProductSearchService {

        public function search($data = array()) {
            $limit = 10;
            $query = isset($data) ? $data : "";

            $baseQuery = Product::take($limit);

            $brand = Brand::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->first();

            $brandId = !empty($brand) ? $brand->id : "";

                return $baseQuery->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('brand_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$brand_id.'%')->get();
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: @cchacholiades I was just writing some stuff up quickly so you would understand the purpose of it. Please look at the answer of edi9999 for a fully working one.

Comment: No problem, goodluck developing your project further. @cchacholiades